# Must Indian passport holders have six-month valid passport to enter Nepal?

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, paperwork, nepal

Do Indian passport holders have to have six-month validity left on their passport to enter Nepal?

I am an Indian passport holder wanting to travel to Nepal soon and do not have enough time to be able to renew my passport which is expiring before 6 months.

So, will I be able to go to Nepal?

Comment: You can travel to Nepal with your Voter ID instead of a passport, if your flight goes directly to/from India and not to any third country.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), the resource used by airport staff, yes you need to have a minimum of 6 months.

> **Passport required**.
>
> Document validity rules: Passports and other documents accepted for
>   entry must be valid for a minimum of **6** months from the arrival date.

The [Tatkaal Passport Service](https://www.india.gov.in/spotlight/passport-seva-portal-convenient-way-get-passport#tab=tab-1) can be used to get passports urgently out-of-turn.  They dispatch within one working day if police verification is not required, if it is then on the third working day.

You can apply through e-Form Submission or apply in person, the linked page has a fee calculator as well as the forms needed to use this service.

Answer (score 4):

Your passport needs to be valid 6 months from the arrival date.

As mentioned by TIMATIC (the database used by airlines):

> **Passport required.**
>
> Passports and other documents accepted for entry **must be
>     valid for a minimum of 6 months from the arrival date.**

This doesn't apply if you have a passport exception as follows:

> **Passport Exemptions:**
>
> Nationals of India with a Voter's Registration Card if arriving directly from India.

As you travel soon and need the passport urgently you can apply for renewal under the Tatkaal scheme.